# Add padding to object in 4-channel image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation, c++

I have a 4-channel image (.png, .tif) like this one:

[image]

I am using OpenCV, and I would like to add padding of type `BORDER_REFLECT` around the flower. `copyMakeBorder` is not useful, since it adds padding to the edges of the image.

I can add certain padding if I split the image in bgr + alpha and apply `dilate` with `BORDER_REFLECT` option on the bgr image, but that solution spoils all the pixels of the flower.

Is there any way to perform a selective `BORDER_REFLECT` padding addition on a ROI defined by a binary mask?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

FYI, the issue has been already addressed and solved here:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/90229/add-padding-to-object-in-4-channel-image/